# running SWF from the command line and getting trace output to the console

Tags: flex4

On windows 7, I installed Flash Builder 4.7 and got the Flex SDK with it (4.9.1, I think). I'm now compiling .as files on the command line. I'm running the resulting SWF files with FlashPlayerDebugger.exe (that came with my trial of Flash Builder 4.7). I'd like to see trace() output on the cmd.exe window, but I don't know how. If I should be using a different way to run the SWF files (perhaps sending them to a browser?) let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command line debugger, [fdb](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffb.html) to see console output.

First, compile a debug SWF:

```
mxmlc -debug=true myApp.mxml
```

Then launch the debugger:

```
java -jar ../lib/fdb.jar
```

Then you can either launch your app in the standalone Flash Player or in a browser. When you see the `(fdb)` prompt, use the `run` debugger command to start your app. You have several choices:

`run <path to SWF>` (launch SWF in the standalone Flash Player)

`run <url to SWF>` or `run <path to HTML file that embeds SWF>` (launch in browser)

Comment: Thanks. I'll upvote your answer once I have enough reputation.